# using lombok @Singular with jackson @JsonPOJOBuilder

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

After debugging through the jackson smile deserializer, I found that my `List` that was annotated with `@Singular` was not being found by jackson.

Is there a way to make `@Singular` with jackson `@JsonPOJOBuilder`?

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class)
@Value
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class MyClass {

    @NonNull String name;
    @NonNull @Singular List<String> favs = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class MyClassBuilder {
    }
}
```

changing  `@Singular` to `@Builder.Default` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you initialize the `favs` field:

```
List<String> favs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Which due to the [@Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) annotation is `final`. Therefore it is not available to be set/overwritten by either the builder or the constructor generated by [@RequiredArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor). Verify, by trying to construct an instance yourself:

```
MyClass.builder().name("a").fav("1").fav("2").build();
```

intellij here says no `fav` method but `@Builder` with `@Singular` should create one.
Solve by:

1. skip the initialization of `favs` at field declaration and let lombok, jackson initialize
2. create you own builder that adds elements on preexisting list

I tested with lombok 1.16.18 and jackson 2.9.2